# In PHP, for a specific key in an associative array, find identical keys and combine values into a single string variable

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have found many references for similar questions on SO but nothing close to what I'm trying to do. I have this array output:

```
0: {id: 1000012, kp_uid: 100000570, assigned_uid: 'tim.hughes@sampleco.com', full_name: 'Tim Hughes'}
1: {id: 1000013, kp_uid: 100000570, assigned_uid: 'brad.slater@sampleco.com', full_name: 'Brad Slater'}
2: {id: 1000014, kp_uid: 100000570, assigned_uid: 'karen.tevis@sampleco.com', full_name: 'Karen Tevis'}
3: {id: 1000015, kp_uid: 100000597, assigned_uid: 'karen.tevis@sampleco.com', full_name: 'Karen Tevis'}
```

I would like to now use 'kp_uid' to locate all common values and then combine the 'full_name' values for each key into a string (with comma separation). Desired outcome from above example will be:

```
0: {kp_uid: 100000570, full_name: 'Tim Hughes, Brad Slater, Karen Tevis'}
1: {kp_uid: 100000597, full_name: 'Karen Tevis'}
```

I have tried many ideas gathered from SO and this was the closest but I can't separate out the unique key:

```
unset($kp_assign['id']);
unset($kp_assign['assigned_uid']);

$result = array();
foreach ($kp_assign as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        $result[$key][] = $val;
    }
}
return $result;
```

Partial results from this show all four names:

```
full_name: Array(4)
0: "Tim Hughes"
1: "Brad Slater"
2: "Karen Tevis"
3: "Karen Tevis"
```

Any direction here will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$items = [
    ['id' => 1000012, 'kp_uid' => 100000570, 'assigned_uid' => 'tim.hughes@sampleco.com', 'full_name' => 'Tim Hughes'],
    ['id' => 1000013, 'kp_uid' => 100000570, 'assigned_uid' => 'brad.slater@sampleco.com', 'full_name' => 'Brad Slater'],
    ['id' => 1000014, 'kp_uid' => 100000570, 'assigned_uid' => 'karen.tevis@sampleco.com', 'full_name' => 'Karen Tevis'],
    ['id' => 1000015, 'kp_uid' => 100000597, 'assigned_uid' => 'karen.tevis@sampleco.com', 'full_name' => 'Karen Tevis']
];

$grouped = [];

// group items by kp_uid
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $grouped[$item['kp_uid']][] = $item;
}

function mapNamesCallback($item)
{
    return $item['full_name'];
}

// iterate over groups and return a single item
// in form of kp_uid => x, full_names => 'name, name2 etc.'
$result = array_map(function ($group, $kpUid) {
    return ['kp_uid' => $kpUid, 'full_name' => implode(', ', array_map('mapNamesCallback', $group))];
}, $grouped, array_keys($grouped));
```

This returns desired result.
I left a few comments in the code for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
unset($kp_assign['id']);
unset($kp_assign['assigned_uid']);

$result = array();
foreach ($kp_assign as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        $result[$key][] = $val;
    }
}

// loop through results, using & to reference original value in array
// you will need to change this to suit the contents of your results array, it is not clear from the example what the keys within the results array will be
foreach ($results as $key => &$val) {
    $val = implode(", ", $val); // implode the names, with comma separator
}

return $result;
```

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't deliver. I got a 500 error. The $&val caused it so I fixed. But the unset does not seem to be working because here is the output: assigned_uid: (4) ['tim.hughes@sampleco.com', 'brad.slater@sampleco.com', 'karen.tevis@sampleco.com', 'karen.tevis@sampleco.com']
full_name: (4) ['Tim Hughes', 'Brad Slater', 'Karen Tevis', 'Karen Tevis']
id: (4) [1000012, 1000013, 1000014, 1000015]
kp_uid: (4) [100000570, 100000570, 100000570, 100000597]

Comment: @ND_Coder sorry about the typo, was supposed to be &$ not $&

Comment: No worries. I just appreciate the help. Debugging is - for me - a big part of my learning. Still don't know why the unset did not function. I will pursue.